# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. error with C#

Tags: c#, mysql

First off, i know this has been asked a million times but i just cannot figure it out what is going wrong.

I have made a local database using Microsoft Management Studio and i want to connect to it through C#. Heres my code:

```
    string connStr = "Server=MSSQLSERVER;Database=UrenRegi;IntegratedSecurity=yes;Uid=auth_windows;";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * From Users", conn);
    MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds, "LoadDataBinding");
    dataGrid.DataContext = ds;
    conn.Close();
```

The error: `Additional information: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.`

Im using windows authentication because i know for sure that it is working.

Comment: My SQL Configuration Manager says the local server i supposed to be called MSSQLSERVER.

Comment: Uid=auth_windows looks strange without Pwd=myPassword; if that`s really my sql ...

Comment: Does "MSSQLSERVER" resolve in DNS to anything? That 'Server' value should be either an IP or something that resolves in DNS.

Comment: It's localhost so i think that shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Can you use the same details to connect to MySQL using the MySQL command line client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Server is not MySQL. Use `SqlConnection` instead of `MySqlConnection` (same for all other classes).

Comment: This and changing my connection string to: `string connStr = "Server= .; Database= UrenRegi; Integrated Security=True;"; ` Worked, thanks alot!